# $f(x)^p=f(x^p)$ for any polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb F_p[x].$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Show that $f(x)^p=f(x^p)$ for any polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb F_p[x].$

I know that the mapping $x \mapsto x^p$ from $\mathbb F_p$ onto $\mathbb F_p$ is an isomorphism. Hence any element $y \in \mathbb F_p$ can be written as $y=z^p$ for some $z \in \mathbb F_p$.
Now I really do not understand from where to start. Any hint or solution will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Maybe, first look at an example. Take $p=2$ and study the equation witihin this case.

Comment: Hint. Use Fermat's (little) Theorem.

Comment: Hints: 1) Try to prove it for $f(x) = x + 1$. 2) If you manage that, then try to extend your proof to $f(x) = ax + b$, where $a,b \in\mathbb{F}_p$. 3) Do your proofs of (1) and (2) give you any ideas?

Comment: Roughly, proceed as follows: for _some_ polynomials in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ this is definitely true. For example, for $f(x)=c\in\mathbb F_p$ (a constant. Hint: use Fermat's Little Theorem) or for $f(x)=x$. Now, prove that this set of polynomials is closed for addition (Hint: use binomial theorem) and multiplication of polynomials (trivial), thus it is a subring on $\mathbb F_p[x]$ containing all constants and $x$, therefore it is the entire $\mathbb F_p[x]$.

Comment: Show that for any $\;a\in\Bbb F_p\;,\;\;a^p=a\;$ . Also read about Fermat's Little Theorem

Comment: Sir can you please provide a solution… It will be very much helpful for me

Comment: BTW $x\mapsto x^p$ in $\mathbb F_p$ is not just an isomorphism, it is really an identity map.

Comment: @MarcoPolo I think you received plenty of hints to work with. Do some work yourself now!

Answer (score 2):

Let $R\subseteq\mathbb F_p[x]$ be defined as

$$R:=\{f\in\mathbb F_p[x]\mid f(x^p)=f(x)^p\}$$

So $R$ is the subset of those polynomials which satisfy the equation $f(x)^p=f(x^p)$ and our goal is to prove that, actually, $R$ is the *entire* $\mathbb F_p[x]$.

Note that there are some obvious elements of $R$:

- Any constant $f(x)=c\in\mathbb F_p$ is in $R$. Namely, if $f=c$, then $f(x)^p=c^p$ and $f(x^p)=c$, but $c^p=c$ per Little Fermat's theorem.
- $f(x)=x$ is in $R$ because $f(x)^p=x^p=f(x^p)$.

$R$ is also *closed for multiplication*: if $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $g,h\in R$, then:

$$f(x)^p=(g(x)h(x))^p=g(x)^ph(x)^p=g(x^p)h(x^p)=f(x^p)$$

Finally, $R$ is *closed for addition*. If $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$, then:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}f(x)^p&=&(g(x)+h(x))^p\\&=&\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k}g(x)^kh(x)^{p-k}\\&=&g(x)^p+h(x)^p\\&=&g(x^p)+h(x^p)\\&=&f(x^p)\end{array}$$

This is because most of the binomial coefficients $\binom{p}{k}$ in the sum above are *divisible by $p$* so they all cancel out. ($\mathbb F_p[x]$ is a ring of characteristic $p$.) The exceptions are $\binom{p}{0}=\binom{p}{p}=1$, i.e. in the sum above, only the first and the last term ($g(x)^p$ and $h(x)^p$ remain.)

(In fact, to elaborate a bit: $\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ so if $1\le k\le p-1$, then $1\le p-k\le p-1$ and so the numerator is divisible by $p$ but none of the factors in the denominator are divisible by $p$ as $p$ is prime.)

---

The bottom line here is that $R$ is a *subring* of $\mathbb F_p[x]$, containing all constants and $f(x)=x$ and so it must be the entire $\mathbb F_p[x]$ because you can "reach" any polynomial in $\mathbb F_p[x]$ by applying additions and multiplications finitely many times starting with constant polynomials and the polynomial $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 2):

The main result you need is this: for $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_p$
$$
(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p\ ,
$$
which itself hinges on ${p\choose k}=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $0<k<p$.

Try proving the result above and generalising to multinomial expressions, i.e.
$$
(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)^p=a^p_1+a^p_2+\cdots+a^p_n\ .
$$

Can you take it from here?